# Next.js 13 current URL

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, next.js13

In SSR when I am using Next.js App Router, How can I get full URL of the current page?

I cannot use `window.location.href` as `window` is not defined and with `useRouter()` I cannot get full URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a middleware.ts (or .js) in the root of your project. (https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware)

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export function middleware(request: Request) {
  const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers);
  requestHeaders.set('x-url', request.url);

  return NextResponse.next({
    request: {
      headers: requestHeaders
    }
  });
}
```

then use headers in your layout or page. (https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/headers#headers)

```
const requestUrl = headers().get('x-url')
```

Comment: You substitute `NextRequest` instance with custom object of `{headers: ...}` shape. It will not work for all cases, e.g with middleware stacking you'll get TS error "Argument of type ... is not assignable to parameter of type NextRequest".

Answer (score 2):

I realise this is not a solution applicable to all use cases or a straightforward answer to the question, but you can use the spread operator to get *all* url params, regardless of how many params there are.
So for example:

```
/app
  - page.tsx
  - layout.tsx
  /[...slug]
    - page.tsx
```

In your /[...slug]

```
const DetailPage = async ({ params }) => {

  console.log(params.slug)

  return (
    <div>...</div>
  )
}
```

So `www.website.com/hello/there/how/are/you` will return `['hello', 'there', 'how', 'are', 'you']`.

And you could then re-construct your url if you know your baseUrl (which I assume you will)

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely right, since there is no window object in SSR
`window.location.href` can't be used and `useRouter()` hook is available on the client side only. However with `useRouter` hook you can get the  current path name in the SSR

**Potential Solution**

install the package `npm install nextjs-current-url`

you can use the `getURL` function from `nextjs-current-url` package. It takes `req` object as input that is available in the `getServerSideProps`.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const { req } = context;
  const the_url = await getUrl({ req });

  return {
    props: {
      the_url,
    },
  };
}
```

Usage in your component

```
const YourComponent = ({ the_url }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{the_url}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default YourComponent;
```

**UPDATED**

You can use it with AppRouter as well. You can just import it and use it with an `await` keyword.

```
import { getUrl } from 'nextjs-current-url';

const YourComponent = () => {
  const url = await getUrl();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{url}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default YourComponent;
```

**UPDATED 2nd version**

remember the example above for serverSideProps, you can use similar approach. you can use the `context` object. The context object contains information about the current request

```
import { getUrl } from 'nextjs-current-url';

const ServerComponentLayout = ({ children }) => {
  const the_url = getUrl({ req: context.req });

  return (
    <div>
      {children}
      <p>URL: {the_url}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ServerComponentLayout;
```

Then in your component

```
<ServerComponentLayout>
  <h1>My Component</h1>
</ServerComponentLayout>
```

Comment: I cannot use `getServerSideProps` as I use AppRouter not PageRouter

Comment: I have just added the UPDATED heading in answer. Actually you can use it with AppRouter as well. you just have to await it. Kindly check and let me me if that helps.

Comment: How can I use it in a server component layout? `getUrl` needs `request` as first argument to work

Comment: Check the updated second version answer. It is almost identical to the getServerSide props thing. I think it will work. Check the updated answer